# OpenCV vector<type> into InputArry cause the data loss problems

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use solvePnP function, but I found that when I chosed vector as the first parameter(it convert into InputArry), the data in the vector had lost. Part of the code is list below:

```
double threeD[POINT_NUM][3] = {{-11, 153, 857}, {-10, 104, 865}, {171, 62, 708}, {172, 50, 714}, {-10, 28, 880}};
    double twoD[POINT_NUM][2] = {{73, 169}, {226, 173}, {313, 850}, {359, 850}, {461, 173}};

    vector<Point3f> outside;
    vector<Point2f> inside;

    for(int i = 0; i != POINT_NUM; ++i){
            outside.push_back(Point3f(threeD[i][0], threeD[i][1], threeD[i][2]));
            inside.push_back(Point2f(twoD[i][0], twoD[i][1]));
    }

    InputArray ia = outside;
    cout << ia.total() << endl;
```

the output number is "0".
My OpenCV version is 2.3. I compiled the code in VS2005.

Comment: i get '5' in both opencv 242 and 300. you probably should update.

Comment: What is your compile tool? Mine is VS2005, and I have try the code in opencv 246. The result is still "0"

Comment: My OS system is Win7-X86.

Comment: I think the problem is cause by VS2005. When I test the code in VS2010, the output is "5". But What can I do to solve the problem in VS2005? Our project is required to use VS2005.

Comment: @berak May I have your contact information?